# Difference between XML 1.0 and XML 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

What is the difference between XML 1.0 and XML 2.0?

Comment: Where do you see Xml 2.0 being used?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There has never been an XML 2.0, even as a draft.

There is a not entirely popular XML 1.1 standard which has three main changes, the most important of which was somewhat controversially applied in-place to XML 1.0 in XML 1.0 5th edition.

It changes the set of allowed element and attribute names (essentially XML 1.0 had a fixed set of names and new characters added to Unicode were not allowed in names; XML 1.1 changed that to an open set such that all currently unallocated code points to be used in names). **This change applies to XML 1.0 5th edition** as well as XML 1.1.

XML 1.1 changed the white space characters treating the IBM NEL terminator U+2028 as an end of line character. It changed the rules around control characters allowing them (apart from code point 0) into XML encoded as numeric character references, so `&#1;` is legal XML 1.1 but not XML 1.0.

Comment: Hehe, alloting "all currently unallocated code points" to be used is going to lead to some fun in the future, I bet. I'm looking forward to being able to use XML element names with whitespace in them. :D

Comment: @AndréMarcondesTeixeira that is version 2 of "canonical xml" not a canonical version of xml 2.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere XML 2.0 , but some proposals for what XML 2.0 might look like:

- elimination of DTDs from syntax,
- integration of namespaces,
- XML Base and XML Information Set (infoset) into the base standard

Search term XML 2.0 on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) page.

There are no much discussions on XML 2.0 , though, I found [this](http://norman.walsh.name/2004/11/10/xml20) little informative.